# Translation of Valmiki Ramayana 3-53-25

Tags: ramayana, ravana, translation-request, sita

The verse is as follows,

> ```
> etat ca anyat ca paruSam vaidehii raavaNa a.nka gaa |
> bhaya shoka samaaviSTaa karuNam vilalaapa ha || 3-53-25
>
> एतत् च अन्यत् च परुषम् वैदेही रावण अंक गा ।
> भय शोक समाविष्टा करुणम् विललाप ह ॥ ३-५३-२५
> ```

The popular translation is as given [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/aranya/sarga53/aranya_53_frame.htm) as,

> On saying this much and other exacting words, Vaidehi who has gone
> onto the flank of Ravana, indeed lamented lamentably as her dismay is
> coalesced with her distress. [3-53-25b, c]

But a person [here](https://www.quora.com/Has-the-millennia-old-Indian-culture-the-epics-such-as-the-Mahabharat-and-the-Ramayan-and-the-religious-texts-and-the-scriptures-been-instrumental-in-creating-a-patriarchal-and-a-women-oppressive-society-that-is-prevalent-in-India-today/answer/Milin-Patel-4/comment/24019065) translates it as,

> On saying this much and other exacting words, Vaidehi, who is on the
> lap of Ravana and is having sexual intercourse with him, indeed moaned
> (in love) as her dismay is coalesced with her coitus.
>
> raavaNa anka gaa= on Ravana's,lap, having sexual intercourse;
> vaidehii= Vaidehi; bhaya shoka samaaviSTaa= dismay, coitus, coalesced
> with; etat ca anyat ca paruSam= this much, also, other, also, sharp
> [saying exacting words]; karuNam vilalaapa ha= [out of] love, moaned,
> indeed.

Can anyone shed some light on this alternate translation. Apparently, literally, either of them can be legitimate.

Comment: lol... the second is not worthy to be called translation... It's hallucination of evil mind..

Comment: @Tezz. I'm in no disagreement here, but I'm having a hard time arguing with the fool.

Comment: शक्यो वारयितुं जलेन हुतभुक् छत्रेण सूर्यातपो ।
नागेन्द्रो निशिताङ्कुशेन समदो दण्डेन गोगर्दभौ ।
व्याधिर्भैषजसङ्ग्रहैश्च विविधैः मन्त्रप्रयोगैर्व्विषम्।
सर्वस्यौषधमस्ति शास्त्रविहितं **मूर्खस्य नास्त्यौषधी** ।।

Comment: Which means "Fire can be extinguished with water. Intense sunlight can be avoided by using umbrella.
An elephant in rut can be controlled applying sharp goad with sharp hook.The bull or the donkey can be kept in place by thorough beating with a stick. Disease also can be treated with the right combination of medicines. Poison ( by snakebite) can be nullified by various chants and spells. In this world, there is some medicine or some solutions for any problem or illness. **But there is no medicine available to cure the foolishness of an idiot..** "

Comment: @VineetMenon On Quora some people interpret things according to their whims and fantasies. To satisfy their whims, they corrupt Sanatana Dharma.

Comment: ROFL!!! Some people!! I can't pinpoint the exact place in the scripture, but Ravana did not touch Sita while she was his captive. She spent her time under a tree in his garden, refusing to even enter his house. Queen Madodari sent her hand maidens to keep Sita company and tried to persuade Ravan to send her back every opportunity she got.

Comment: @UdayKrishna, Not only one word. His version of translation has numerous  errors like the word, gA, vilApa, shokA etc.

Comment: @Vineet Menon, Sanskrit,Sanskriti and Sanskaar-  were deeply connected, in the Yuga of the Ramayana.This particular translator should ideally stay away from Sanskrit. I wanted to know the correct translation of a verse and read the answer. Aim achieved! Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

There is a website developed and maintained by IIT Kanpur. It is Valmiki Ramayana project by Rashtriya Sanskrita Vidya Peetham, Tirupati. I am providing the translation from the same [source](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=3&language=dv&field_sarga_value=53).

> एतच्चान्यच्च परुषं वैदेही रावणाङ्कगा।।3.53.25।।
>
> भयशोकसमाविष्टा करुणं विललाप ह।
>
> रावणाङ्कगा a lady under Ravana's grip, वैदेही Vaidehi (Sita), भयशोकसमाविष्टा full of fear and sorrow, एतत् च these words, अन्यच्च and other words, परुषम् harsh, करुणम् piteously, विललाप ह wept.
>
> Sita, daughter of Videha, full of sorrow and fear under Ravana's grip uttered these partly harsh and partly piteous wordsweeping.